# Gitlab CI invokes docker install.sh and always runs instruction with Sudo

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab-ci, sudo

I am trying to run gitlab ci which contains custom php image. The before_script invokes `docker_install.sh`
In `docker_install.sh` I executed `whoami` it gives "docker". I tried to list down groups it gives "docker sudo".

When I try to execute further instructions in `docker_install.sh` file, like

```
cp ci/php.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

It does not execute and gives error `cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini': Permission denied`

If I do
`sudo cp ci/php.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini`
it executes successfully. However there are many such instruction for which I do not want to append `sudo`.

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Docker user doesn't have root permissions.

Gitlab CI doesn't allow you modifying the user

One way is to derive FROM the original image by Dockerfile set user to USER root and after you have finished with your installation back to USER docker. Or leave it at root and just run your CI job.

Another less secure way is using su-exec (instead of sudo)
https://github.com/ncopa/su-exec

Comment: With first proposed solution, like setting user to root, can we set the user "root" in gitlab ci rather than original FROM image? that way we do not need to change the image. and then once the execution is done, we can change user back to "docker"

Comment: @Vimal That's not possible at the moment. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#extended-docker-configuration-options

Comment: YES, no way at the moment. You HAVE derive from the original image if it has a user different than root .